# How to make the two CrawlerSpider Rules to cooperate

Tags: python, scrapy

I use [this CrawlerSpider example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example) as 'backbone' for my Crawler.

I want to implement this idea:

First Rule follows the links. Then matched links are passed further to second rule, where second rule matches new links according to the pattern and calls callback on them.

For example, i have Rules:

```
...

start_urls = ['http://play.google.com/store']

rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/store/apps',))),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/details\?id=',)), callback='parse_app'),
)

...
```

How i expect that parser will work:

1. Open http://play.google.com/store' and matches first URL 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/SHOPPING/collection/topselling_free'
2. Pass found URL ('https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/SHOPPING/collection/topselling_free') to second Rule
3. Second Rule tries to match it's pattern (allow=('.*/details\?id=',))) and, if it's matched, calls callback 'parse_app' for that URL.

Atm, Crawler just walks through all links and doesn't parse anything.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to parse the links which match the pattern "/store/apps/.*/details\?id=" ?

Comment: @XuJiawan, yes, but firstly i need to go thorugh all links that match first Rule and only then extract from those matched URLs other URLs that match second Rule.

Answer (score 1):

As Xu Jiawan implies, URLs matching `/details\?id=` also match `/store/apps` (from what I saw briefly)

So try changing the order of the rules to have the `parse_app` Rule match first:

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/details\?id=',)), callback='parse_app'),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/store/apps',))),
)
```

Or use `deny`

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/store/apps',), deny=('/details\?id=',))),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/details\?id=',)), callback='parse_app'),
)
```

If you want the first Rule() to be applied *only* on 'http://play.google.com/store' and then use the second Rule() to call `parse_app`, you may need to implement [parse_start_url](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url) method
to generate Requests using `SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/store/apps',))`

Something like

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item

class PlaystoreSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'playstore'
    #allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://play.google.com/store']

    rules = (
        #Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/store/apps',), deny=('/details\?id=',))),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/details\?id=',)), callback='parse_app'),
    )

    def parse_app(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an app page! %s' % response.url)
        # do something


    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return [Request(url=link.url)
                for link in SgmlLinkExtractor(
                    allow=('/store/apps',), deny=('/details\?id=',)
                ).extract_links(response)]
```